# Action not found for the Play(2.6.0) Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am  using `Intellij Idea + Play 2.6.0 + com.google.code.play2-maven-plugin` to setup the development envrironment.

1. My controllere class `HomeController` is placed in the following structure(`app` is the source root)

   `app
     controllers
        HomeController`

The code is:

```
    package controllers
    import javax.inject._
    import play.api.mvc._

    @Singleton
    class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {
     def index = Action {
        Ok("Hello,World")
      }

      def count = Action {
        Ok("10")
      }
     }
```

2. The `routers` file is:

   `GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
   GET     /count                      controllers.HomeController.count`

When I run the maven goal: `play2:run`, the server starts up, when I
access `http://localhost:9000/ or http://localhost:9000/count`, each says  `Action Not Found for request '/'` and `Action Not Found for request '/count'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller class name is **HomeController2** but your router points to **controllers.HomeController**.

Choose a solution :)

- change routes to **HomeController2.count**, and **HomeController2.index** (in this case your controller source code is okay)
- **OR** move your class to controllers package (add **package controllers** to the top of your source code) and rename it to HomeController (in this case your routes is correct)

Comment: Thanks @balage for the answer. Sorry it is my fault,  I did use `HomeController` in my project,but when I asked the question, I somehow added a `2`.., So, With `HomeController`， the problem is still there..

Comment: @Tom I've tried your controller in a new project and it works. in my project, the controller class source is:
`
    package controllers

    import javax.inject._

    import play.api.mvc._

    @Singleton
    class HomeController2 @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

      def index = Action {
        Ok("Hello,World")
      }

      def count = Action {
        Ok("10")
      }
    }
`
routes:
`
    GET        /                    controllers.HomeController2.index
    GET        /count               controllers.HomeController2.count
`

Comment: sorry for the unformatted code.
controller: https://pastebin.com/xqFz0CV8
routes: https://pastebin.com/dz5hVzPB

Comment: Thanks @balage for your helpful answer. After reading your comment, I checked my pom.xml again compared with https://github.com/play2-maven-plugin/play2-maven-test-projects/blob/test-projects-1.0.0-rc1/play26/scala/starter-example/pom.xml, I figured out the problem, the pom packaging should be ` <packaging>play2</packaging>`

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the problem, the `pom.xml` should use `<packaging>play2</packaging>`,

The `HomeController` example is learned from https://github.com/play2-maven-plugin/play2-maven-test-projects/tree/master/play26/scala/starter-example

Thanks @balage for helping in figuring out the problem.